# Is it possible to have a "quick edit" (inline-editing of another file, nested buffers) feature through plugins?

Tags: vim-windows, plugin-system

I wanted to know if it's possible through plugin mechanism to insert another "pane" in the middle of the buffer I'm editing. The ultimate feature that I want is inlining piece code which exists in some other file. A very good example is how brackets code editor lets you edit css from another file within html:

[image]

I couldn't find any existing vim plugin to do this, so I thought I'll begin by asking if there are any fundamental (perhaps terminal-GUI level) limitations which could prevent you from doing this

Comment: this is not possible

Comment: You could get something interesting going with splits

Answer (score 1):

> if there are any fundamental (perhaps terminal-GUI level) limitations

Normal windows are always tiled, popup windows are read-only. Hence if you "insert another pane in the middle", then you can't edit it anymore.

Vim is designed with split window / switch buffer paradigm in mind. Just get used to this.

Comment: in vim, popup windows are not necessarily read only, but do have limited editing capabilities.  In neovim, floating windows are just regular windows, so no issue there.